# I want to replace hamburger icon with back icon in GalleryFragment

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to how to change hamburger icon to back icon. Below i have provide GalleryFragment.java

```html
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.thechamp.myapplication.R;

public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {



    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_gallery);
        

        return root;
    }
}
```

and here i am providing MainActivity.java
I have tried various ways but every time i got error. I want back icon in Fragment's Action bar, so that user can get back from that fragment to HomeFragment.

```html
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

Here is all coding of my project. Please help me to change icon

Answer (score 1):

As per the [AppBarConfiguration documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#appbarconfiguration), the IDs you pass into the `AppBarConfiguration.Builder` are the 'top-level destinations':

> Top-level destinations do not display an Up button in the top app bar because there is no higher level destination. By default, the start destination of your app is the only top-level destination. When the user is at a top-level destination, the Navigation button becomes a drawer icon if the destination uses a DrawerLayout.

So by adding `R.id.nav_gallery` to that list, you are specifically opting in that destination to show the hamburger icon on that destination. This is indeed the expected way to handle different destinations in your `NavigationView` - they are sibling screens that are not hierarchically related to each other and perfect candidates for being top level destinations (you should **not** expect destinations in your `NavigationView` to show an up arrow, despite the system back button taking you back to the start destination of your graph).

But if you really do want to show the Up arrow, just remove the `R.id.nav_gallery` from your `AppBarConfiguration.Builder`:

```
mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
    R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_slideshow)
    .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
    .build();
```